# How to disable lighting inside a tile's occluder?

Tags: godot

I`m doing a platformer game that has platfroms on which player can jump and go though them.

I have a TileMap with my TileSet. The platforms are in this TileSet. Every tile has its light occluder (with 2nd light mask). I added a PointLight2D node to player's scene and enabled shadows for 2nd light mask. Every tile casts shadow but when player goes though the platform, the PointLigth2D lights platform inside.

How can i fix it?
[The bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVaqS.png)

There's also a second type of platforms. It brokes when the player is standing on it. It has own LightOccluder2D node. When player is going through it, shadows disappear and platforms doesn't highlight. I think there's a problem with TileMap.
When the player goes through the platform, the shadow should disappear but platform doesn't have to highlight like on the photo.p